# Chern character

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to read the book “Fourier-Mukai transforms in algebraic geometry”. Around the end of the page 126 of this book, it is written that the Chern character is from $K(X)$ (Grothendieck group) to $H^*(X,\mathbb{Q})$. However, according to Fulton’s intersection theory book or Hartshorne’s algebraic geometry book, the Chern character is from $K(X)$ to $A(X)$ (Chow ring). Now, my question is that how is this possible? Indeed, how can we look at the Chern character with codomain $H^*(X,\mathbb{Q})$? One answer to this question could be that we consider the composition with cycle map, but then, if we do this, why do we again have Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch theorem or indeed Theorem 5.26, page 127, “Fourier-Mukai transforms in algebraic geometry”?

Comment: Compose $\operatorname{ch}:K(X) \to A(X)$ with the cycle class map $A(X) \to H^*(X,\mathbb Q)$.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks for your comment. I guess I found this at the first time when I was searching for it and I forgot. Now, my question is that why if we do this, then again we have Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch (Indeed Thm 5.26 in “Fourier-Mukai transforms in algebraic geometry”?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question.

Comment: Because intersection of cycles factors through the cycle map and intersection in cohomology.

Comment: @TabesBridges I was looking at Fultons book and I noticed that as it is stated in Fulton, cycle map goes to Borel-Moore homology and what I am asking is the sheaf cohomology with rational coefficients. How can I relate these to each other?

Comment: @PouyaLayeghi Borel Moore homology and standard cohomology are the same if the space is smooth.

Comment: @Roland Thanks. May you give a reference for this?

Comment: I don't have a reference. It is mentioned in the wikipedia article on Borel-Moore homology and there are several sources. I guess they all talk about it, I mean this Poincare duality is really an important property of Borel-Moore homology.